# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm running a WordPress website for a client and getting this in the console.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#]

I know about this error with the latest WordPress update:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])

However my error seems to be something else. Can anyone tell me what I should be looking at to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you using the expression? Show us the code

Comment: Can you elaborate on this being an issue with the latest version of WordPress?

Comment: related: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2885

Comment: You need to use quotes

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the `#` in quotes in the selector so that it is not interpreted as an `id` selector:

```
$('[href="#"]');

$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]);
```

Comment: $('a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"]); this worked for me. Replace * with a ^

Answer (score 0):

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

> Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings.

and

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_);

`#` is not a valid identifier, so you have to represent it as a string, so you have to surround it with quotes.

Such:

```
a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])
```